# How to require Windows logon to Samba share (on Ubuntu server) every time or with short timeout?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, samba

I'm setting my kids up with accounts on my home server to be able to access *some* stuff that's there. There's two shared computers (Win 7 and Win 10) they all have access to, and I'd like them to have to sign in to access the samba shares every time; so if one of them signs in and does something, then another one goes on a little later, they'll have to sign in over again. Currently Win 7 just seems to remember the first logon until reboot. But I don't want me on my Win 7 machine to face the same thing; it should keep using the logon stored in the credentials vault.

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `deadtime` configuration parameter of
[smb.conf](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html) :

> **deadtime (G)**
>
> The value of the parameter (a decimal integer) represents the number
> of minutes of inactivity before a connection is considered dead, and
> it is disconnected. The deadtime only takes effect if the number of
> open files is zero.
>
> This is useful to stop a server's resources being exhausted by a large
> number of inactive connections.
>
> Most clients have an auto-reconnect feature when a connection is
> broken so in most cases this parameter should be transparent to users.
>
> Using this parameter with a timeout of a few minutes is recommended
> for most systems.
>
> A deadtime of zero indicates that no auto-disconnection should be
> performed.
>
> Default: *deadtime = 10080*
>
> Example: *deadtime = 15*

Comment: It certainly reads that way; but it doesn't seem to achieve it in practise. The Windows machine just keeps opening shares without asking for authentication, even when I leave it longer than the deadtime I've set.

Comment: Windows might support auto-reconnect. Maybe coupled it with a Windows action : Check if running `net use * /delete` after the disconnection causes Windows to re-ask for the password. If it works, schedule it to run every N minutes.

Comment: Works a treat in Win 7. Win 10 isn't playing nice; but that's because it won't even ask for a logon when accessing the shares.

Comment: The share logon might need to be deleted from the Credential Manager

Comment: This machine has never logged into the samba shares before. I even had to set the workgroup when I was trying. Whereas on Win 7 it asks for logon as soon as I open the remote server, Win 10 just opens it and displays nothing. If I manually enter a share path in the address bar then it asks, but that's not what I want.

Comment: Fixed that; samba was reverting failed logons to"bad user" i.e. guest. Changed that and all seems to be up and going. Excellent thanks.